# Actionbar occupies entire screen when home button is displayed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I faced this problem while using ActionBar and struggled to find the solution,found it with help from others and a lot of searching.

So, this was the problem, 
I wanted to display the home button and title in the ActionBar and used

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Well this should work theoretically, but it didnt. for some reason the "setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);" also made the action bar occupy the entire screen.

so i had to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to this was to change the style the actionBar got it from.

i was originally using

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
            <item name="android:background">#000000</item>                                           
</style>
```

Later changed it to

```
"@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar
```

This appears in actionbar Sherlock too, [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/Cnd7Qcx4xTw) is where the solution was found.

and this helped solve the problem. So anyone facing a similar scenario,pls try changing the style. Hope this helps.